# X.509 certificate renew vs. rekey

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, x.509

What is the difference from CA perspective between renewal and rekeying of the certificate previously issued by this CA?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [RFC 3647: *Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure -- Certificate Policy and Certification Practices Framework*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3647):

> 4.4.6.  Certificate Renewal
>
> This subcomponent is used to describe the following elements
> related    to certificate renewal.  Certificate renewal means the
> issuance of a    new certificate to the subscriber without changing
> the subscriber or    other participant's public key or any other
> information in the    certificate:
>
> - Circumstances under which certificate renewal takes place, such
>   as
>   where the certificate life has expired, but the policy permits the
>   same key pair to be reused;

Which contradicts itself in that it initially states that during renewal you cannot change the *public key or any other information in the certificate*, but then goes on to say that a renewal can take place *where the certificate life has expired*.

and...

> 4.4.7.  Certificate Re-key
>
> This subcomponent is used to describe the following elements
> related    to a subscriber or other participant generating a new key
> pair and    applying for the issuance of a new certificate that
> certifies the new    public key:
>
> - Circumstances under which certificate re-key can or must take
>   place, such as after a certificate is revoked for reasons of key
>   compromise or after a certificate has expired and the usage period
>   of the key pair has also expired;

Comment: Not sure there's a contradiction in the way you're thinking. Sure, if you count notBefore and notAfter as "information" in the certificate, one could read it as a contradiction, but in the classical sense, this is simply a limitation on lifetime, and doesn't confer any information as to the certificates capabilities or cryptographic restrictions. For example, a renewal of a certificate shouldn't add or remove a Key Usage/Extended Key Usage attribute, change the DN, or add extra SubjectAltName aliases. Performing any of these actions is a reissuance rather than a renewal.

Comment: @Tyzoid - I couldn't agree with you more. It's an academic argument whether lifetime counts as _information_, or as you say, a _limitation on lifetime_.  At a push, the RFC could have been worded better maybe?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quote from [Symantec's Certificate Policy statement](https://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/about/media/repository/stn-cp.pdf):

> Generally speaking, both “Rekey” and “Renewal” are 
>   commonly described as “Certificate Renewal”, focusing on the fact that the old Certificate is being replaced with a new Certificate and not emphasizing whether or not a new key pair is generated.

Then they define Rekey and Renew as (emphasis mine)

> **Certificate renewal** is the issuance of a new certificate to the subscriber without changing the public key or any other information in the certificate. Certificate renewal is supported for Class 3 certificates where the key pair is generated on a web server as most web server key generation 
>   tools permit the creation of a new Certificate Request for an existing key pair.
>
> **Certificate rekey** is the application for the issuance of a new certificate that certifies the new public key. Certificate rekey is supported for all certificate Classes.

Really just comes down to policy.  A CA could decide that it will always prohibit issuance of a certificate using a key already certified.  Having (and enforcing) that policy requires a more expensive issuance process than merely verifying that the subject identification material is valid, since they would need to compare the public key to all previously issued certificates.

The CA/Browser Forum's [Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.4.2.pdf) has no stipulations for renewal or re-key (sections 4.6 and 4.7), and the [Extended Validation requirements](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/EV-V1_6_1.pdf) don't seem to mention the keys.